# Debugging Bing Maps JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, virtual-earth

I'm using the Bing Maps / Virtual Earth control and it appears to be working, however Firebug in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome are reporting an uncaught exception in Microsoft's `mapcontrol.ashx` file. I'm concerned that this may be caused by a bug in my code interacting with Bing Maps.

As this JavaScript file is minified I can find no way of debugging it. Is there an un-minified version available or another option for finding what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no uncompressed version of the control's script. The only options are standard JavaScript debugging techniques.

Reference: [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vemapcontroldev/thread/002b1414-1d81-4157-b25b-9ce0bbf4f86f).